# MySQL Variables PHP COnnections

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I'm using a PHP web application to connect to MySQL, what I would like to do is set the userID of the client who has logged in and then use that MySQL variables within views and functions to limit data returned.

Currently, I'm simply using:-

```
SET @UserID = 3;
```

And then referencing this within views/functions.

Is this a suitable and reliable method to do this across multiple concurrent user sessions? Will this be present for the lifetime of that users MySQL connection (or page load) from PHP and I obviously want to ensure no other connections leverage this. It's set on every page load (or MySQL reconnection from my app).

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it clearly states in the first paragraph of the mysql variables man page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

> *User-defined variables are session-specific.* That is, a user variable defined by one client cannot be seen or used by other clients. All variables for a given client session are automatically freed when that client exits.

e.g. they exist while the php<->mysql connection is kept alive, PER connection, and automatically removed when the connection is closed/terminated. Unless you're using persistent connections in PHP (which you shouldn't be anyways), the mysql variables would basically exist for the life of that particular script invocation, and will NOT be available when the same user comes back with another http request later.

Comment: Are persistent connections different from a connection pool?

Comment: persistent connections are kept in a pool while not being used. generally they're a BAD idea in a web context. e.g. some script barfs half-way through a complicated transaction. since the connection's persistent, mysql+php leave it open. some OTHER script then shows up, reuses the connection, and starts doing its own stuff. You can easily end up in a deadlock situation, because script #2 has no idea it's working in the middle of script #1's half-completed transaction. If the connection had closed when #1 aborted, the transactiou would've rolled back automatically.

Comment: Persistent connections are good and deadlock situation is not a problem.

Comment: well, enjoy your site going down because your persistent connection pool got locked up with a ton of incomplete transactions.

Comment: If you're using transactions and you don't have a database layer that can recover from exceptions an abandon them then that's a problem with your database layer, not persistent connections in general. Other languages use persistent connections and transactions without issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, strictly speaking, what you're doing shouldn't be a problem (each PHP connection exists more-or-less independantly). But, that said, it isn't the best approach.

I think you've got a "if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail" problem. MySQL is not designed with the request lifecycle in mind, and it shouldn't need to be aware of it. PHP, on the other hand, is designed with exactly that idea.

Instead of:

```
mysqli_query('Set @UserID=' . $id);
$output = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE ID=@UserID');
```

Why not just use [bound variables?](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Looks like you just missed the question

Comment: I think it's worth restating that this sort of thing is a Very Bad Idea and is why bindings should be specified for each query specifically rather than relying on the connection context to provide them for you.